# How can I correctly set a Dye into an ItemStack?

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I'm trying to apply a [Dye](http://jd.bukkit.org/beta/apidocs/org/bukkit/material/Dye.html) color into an existing [ItemStack](http://jd.bukkit.org/beta/apidocs/org/bukkit/inventory/ItemStack.html), how can I do this without using deprecated methods and creating an new stack?

I tried the following code but it's resulting in a normal ink sack.

ps: I'm creating an stack in the first line only as example.

```
final ItemStack stack = new ItemStack(Material.INK_SACK);
Dye dye = new Dye();
dye.setColor(DyeColor.LIME);
stack.setData(dye);
```

edit: Added final to stack variable to show that it cannot be replaced by a new stack.

Comment: If you really want to use non-deprecated code, I updated my answer with a custom `enum` you could create, although I still don't think its necessary until bukkit implements a new, non-deprecated way to do this, but, if you really want to, you can use the custom `enum`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've found a way to do this, but it is nowhere near as efficient as using a deprecated method. Here it is with my own personal thought process along the way.

The problem with your current attempt is the interior of the `setData(MaterialData)` method.

```
public void setData(MaterialData data) {
    Material mat = getType();

    if (data == null || mat == null || mat.getData() == null) {
        this.data = data;
    } else {
        if ((data.getClass() == mat.getData()) || (data.getClass() == MaterialData.class)) {
            this.data = data;
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Provided data is not of type " + mat.getData().getName() + ", found " + data.getClass().getName());
        }
    }
}
```

This method works as a simple setter that handles null values and prevents incorrect data types. The problem here should be quite visible though. Wools and dyes don't store their info in `MaterialData`, they store it in their durability. The durability of a `Colorable` object determines its color. Being that this is the case, you will need to modify the durability in order to do anything to the color. The only place you can set the durability outside of the constructor is the `setDurability` method. This doesn't take a `MaterialData`, only a `short`. Thus our options are the following: Construct a new ItemStack, or gain non-deprecated access to a usable `short` value. By your criteria, we move to the latter.

First point of entry, the `DyeColor` class. If we can't find the `short` value here, it will at least be supplied from here to another class. Looking at the source gives us a grim reminder of just how rooted in deprecation the problem is.

There is one hacky solution using `DyeColor` alone, but it's not version proof incase of changes. The `Enum.ordinal()` method will return the ordinal value of an enum. This is the numerical value of the order it was defined. Starting from index zero, it will match the wool data values, but needs to be inverted for dyes, something you are trying to make universal. The option is there though.

So `DyeColor` is out of the question, but it got me thinking. The `Dye` class as a `MaterialData` works perfectly fine when using the `toItemStack()` method. Maybe we could use that. Turns out you can! It will require creating a new `Itemstack`, but we will use the new `ItemStack` to access data for the original one. Firstly, we create the `MaterialData` like you did above.

```
Dye dye = new Dye();
dye.setColor(DyeColor.LIME);
```

Next, convert the `Dye` into an `Itemstack` using the `toItemStack()` method.

```
ItemStack tempStack = dye.toItemStack();
```

Now hold on, why does this work? Well you see, the `Dye.setColor(DyeColor)` method has an internal implementation of the following:

```
public void setColor(DyeColor color) {
    setData(color.getDyeData());
}
```

It uses a deprecated method, but because it's wrapped in a DyeColor call, it's not deprecated to the plugin user. Please note: THIS IS PERFECTLY ACCEPTABLE! Many of Bukkit's calls using `Material` as a parameter actually just call the deprecated method with the type id associated to it. It's perfectly valid to call those methods though. Also note that the `setData(byte)` method is just a simple setter.

Next up, the `toItemStack()` method.

```
public ItemStack toItemStack(int amount) {
    return new ItemStack(type, amount, data);
}
```

We can see here that the `DyeColor` that was converted to a byte is now sent to the `ItemStack` constructor `ItemStack(Material, int, short)` as the durability (it automatically casts to a `short`). This means, we now have the short we require! It's stored in the durability of `tempStack`. To top it all off, we do the following.

```
stack.setDurability(tempStack.getDurability());
stack.setData(dye);
```

It's over. You have a modified `ItemStack` with no exposed deprecated methods. You may be asking though why I still call `ItemStack.setData(MaterialData)`. This just ensures that if someone tries to access the `DyeColor` from the ItemStack's `MaterialData` it will match up with the durability.

I hope you are satisfied with the fact that it is possible, but I still just recommend using the deprecated methods until they are listed as broken (which usually doesn't happen with Bukkit).

Answer (score 1):

`DyeColor.*` actually uses wool colors, and Mojang decided to switch dye colors and wool colors around. So, `DyeColor.LIME.getData()` returns 5, which is lime wool, but lime dye is 10. So you need to use `byte data = (byte) (15 - DyeColor.COLOR.getData());`

So, here's what your code should look like:

```
DyeColor color = DyeColor.LIME //or whatever dye color you want
byte data = (byte) (15 - color.getData()); //use byte data = (byte) (color.getData()) if you're coloring wool

ItemStack itm = new ItemStack(Material.INK_SACK, 1, data);
```

This would give you an ItemStack with 1 lime dye.

If you would really like to use a non-deprecated method, you could make your own enum with their ID's:

```
public enum CustomDyeColor{

    BLACK(0), //ink sack
    RED(1),
    GREEN(2),
    BROWN(3),
    BLUE(4), //lapis lazuli
    PURPLE(5),
    CYAN(6),
    LIGHT_GRAY(7),
    GRAY(8),
    PINK(9),
    LIME(10),
    YELLOW(11),
    LIGHT_BLUE(12),
    MAGENTA(13),
    ORANGE(14),
    WHITE(15); //bonemeal

    private byte data;
    CustomDyeColor(int i){
      this.data = (byte) i;
    }

    public byte getData(){
      return this.data;
    }
}
```

And then you could use your new, non-depricated, custom code to get the data values like this:

```
CustomDyeColor color = CustomDyeColor.LIME;
byte customData = color.getData();

ItemStack item = new ItemStack(Material.INK_SACK, 1, customData)l
```

Comment: But [getData() is deprecated](http://jd.bukkit.org/rb/apidocs/org/bukkit/DyeColor.html#getData()) . I could also use [getDyeData()](http://jd.bukkit.org/rb/apidocs/org/bukkit/DyeColor.html#getDyeData()) that uses dye colors but it's also deprecated :/

Comment: @JoséRobertoAraújoJúnior Just because it's deprecated doesn't mean it doesn't work... There is still no clear way on how to do this without using deprecated methods

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the Dye(Material) constructor, then appying your DyeColor, and converting the Material to an ItemStack.

```
Dye dye = new Dye(Material.INK_SACK);
dye.setColor(...);
ItemStack coloredInkSack = dye.toItemStack();
```

Comment: `toItemStack()` creates a new stack instance, I'm trying to keep reference to the original object

Comment: There is no "original object" before you call toItemStack. It is useless to have an original object anyways, since Dye and MaterialData are like represented ItemStack builders, saving creation for the end.

Answer (score 0):

I did it like so:

```
new ItemStack(Material.STAINED_GLASS_PANE, 1, DyeColor.BLACK.getData()));
```

With the 1.8.8 Spigot it actually creates 1 black glass pane, although it says the `getData()` on the color is deprecated.
I think it also works with wool and clay.